# CSS Pseudo Selector "Blocking" Angular Ng-Click?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a css table-card layout that uses the `:before` pseudo selector to insert the header name.

Also in my table, I created a button that fires an alert when pressed.

The problem is that the button does not work in the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZKweKp

But when I take the css out, the buttons work as expected.

Here's the css:

```
.cards tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
    background: #eee; 
}

.cards th { 
    background: #333; 
    color: white; 
}
.cards td, 
.cards th {
    padding: 6px; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    text-align: left; 
}

/* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
.cards table, 
.cards thead, 
.cards tbody, 
.cards th, 
.cards td, 
.cards tr { 
    display: block; 
}

/* Hide table headers (but not display: none; for accessibility) */
.cards th {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}

.cards tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

.cards td { 
    /* Behave  like a "row" */
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 20%; 
}

.cards td:before { 
    /* Now like a table header */
    position: absolute;
    /* Top/left values mimic padding */
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    width: 45%; 
    padding-right: 10px; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.cards td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Date"; }
.cards td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "User"; }
```

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>

  <script data-require="angular.js@~1.4.0" data-semver="1.4.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="IndexController">

  <table class='cards'>
    <tr>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Button</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="color in pageData.colors">
      <td>{{ color }}</td>
      <td>
        <button ng-click="pageFn.clickMe()">Click Me</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

And the JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('IndexController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.pageData ={};
  $scope.pageFn = {};

  $scope.pageData.colors = ['This is red. etc... ', 'This is green. etc...', 'Blue text here... asdfadsfadsfadsf a'];

  $scope.pageFn.clickMe = function () {
    console.log('hello');
    alert('clicked!');
  }

});
```

Comment: On `.cards td:before` the `width: 45%;` goes over the button - if you remove that property it works. Where you have the button you could add another class that removes the width property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your CSS of `.cards td:before` to this,

```
.cards td:before { 
    /* Now like a table header */
    position: absolute;
    /* Top/left values mimic padding */
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    width: auto; 
    padding-right: 10px; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

`width:45%` changed to `width:auto;`,which was preventing the button to get clicked.